# setting alarm label in Tizen

Tags: tizen

Any body know how to set a label for an alarm in tizen programaticaly, when the alarm trigger it should not open any other application, it should show the given text.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

By "show the given text" I assume you want to show a full screen app or a popup.

Here are a few ways to do this.

1. You could pass your own app ID and [handle this event](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=/dev-guide/2.4/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__CAPI__ALARM__MODULE.html#gafac0e4fc42f5553f2f0c788dc9361e02).
2. For popups, you could use [EFL Timer API](https://developer.tizen.org/development/api-references/native-application?redirect=/dev-guide/2.3.1/org.tizen.native.mobile.apireference/group__Ecore__Timer__Group.html).
3. I wouldn't recommend this but you could package [two apps as part of your package](https://developer.tizen.org/forums/general-support/package-two-applications-one). One app could then invoke the other.